# 18.04 "Software & Updates" won't let me select/deselect repositories/PPA's in "Other Software" tab

Tags: 18.04

In 18.04, **Software & Updates** won't let me select/deselect repositories/PPA's in the "Other Software" tab.

However, if while in **terminal** I type:

```
sudo software-properties-gtk
```

I am able to select/deselect repositories/PPA's in the "Other Software" tab.

Anybody have suggestions on where to look for a problem, or a fix?

**Update #1:**

At the login screen, if I select **GNOME** or **Unity**, then it all works fine. If I select **GNOME on Xorg** or **Ubuntu**, it doesn't work. Also, if I start Synaptic, which asks for the admin password after launch, it all works fine too.

Comment: Are using Gnome Desktop or Unity Desktop?

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix GNOME

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A **workaround** for this problem...

- start `Synaptic`
- enter the admin password
- choose **Repositories** from the **Settings** menu
- enable/disable/edit repositories as desired
- close the window when done
- click the **Reload** button after closing this window

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me and in my case it was due to some errors in Gnome (if you are using it). Basically when you click any repository the "asking for password" popup should appear, but at times it didn't show. So it was asking for the admin password but you could not see that. Therefore you could not select anything. It was hidden somehow and only after pressing Alt+F2 then r and enter (to restart gnome) I could see the popup and then everything worked.

Basically when you go to Software and Updates and click a repository and nothing happens, just restart Gnome and see if it works. It does for me.

Comment: Good suggestion, but it seems that I don't have the same problem/fix.

Answer (score 0):

I found this article, [21 Best things to do after installing Ubuntu 18.04](https://www.ubuntupit.com/best-things-to-do-after-installing-ubuntu/). From it this advise:

### 2.  Enable Additional Repositories

> Ubuntu doesn’t come, by default, with enabling additional
> repositories. Before updating and upgrading your Ubuntu system must
> allow the additional canonical repositories.  To do so, search for
> software & update. In the other software tab, enables “Canonical
> Partners.” Now close the window, ignore if it says reload.

Disagreeing with the author a bit, when it says it wants to reload and asks for admin password, I have the habit of complying.

Also a bonus picture :):

[image]

---

### Another Option to try

If memory serves me correctly I ran into a similar problem with Ubuntu 16.04 under Unity but can't say for sure. If the author's recommendation doesn't fix the problem, then in the picture above click on the preceding tab `Ubuntu Software`. Now eusure the options for **(universe)** and **(multiverse)** are checked.

Comment: Thanks for the help! I checked the settings of "Canonical Partners" and the universe and multiverse options, and they're set fine. I did notice that if change any options on the "Ubuntu Software" or "Updates" tabs, it does ask me for the admin password... although just changing anything on the "Other Software" tab doesn't ask for the admin password... and also, even though the checkmark doesn't change, it does ask to update the database when I close the window.

Comment: The password is only required when it wants to run `sudo apt update` in the background. This also happens if you add or remove a PPA I believe.

Comment: I think that's part of the problem. It's not asking for the password when I make any changes on the "Other Software" tab, or when it asks me to update the database. I just tried reinstalling "Software & Updates", but it didn't help.

Comment: Please see my update #1 in my question. Thanks.

Comment: @heynnema I read your update and you mention where it works fine. You neglected to mention where it doesn't work fine :)

Comment: You're just too fast for me :-) I was just coming back to edit that info into my update.

Answer (score 0):

I recently ran into this problem in 18.10 which comes default with the Gnome desktop.

I ran `sudo update-manager` from the terminal which allowed me to select/deselect additional providers without needing the pop-up to show up.